# javascript exception object format

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, object

By default, Node.js throws the following exception when a file is not found.

```
{ [Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'InvalidFile']
  errno: 34,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'InvalidFile',
  syscall: 'open' }
```

Technically speaking, this is supposed to be a JavaScript Object. As per the javascript object sematics, there should be a comma to separate member elements. In this case, there is no comma between `[Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'InvalidFile']` and `errno: 34,`. My questions are

1. How do I construct an object like this?
2. How do I access the
   `[Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'InvalidFile']` element
   in a program?

Comment: The official JavaScript exception object Error has many constructors for specific purposes, such as SyntaxError. The standard properties of Error include`message` (the error message), `name` (a name for the error), and (on some platforms) `stack` (containing the stack trace).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it's not entirely code. It's based on JavaScript's literals syntax, but is just a representation of a the object that's generated from [`util.inspect()`](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) (or a similar internal function).

The square brackets mention the *type* of [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) before its [`message`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/message). And, the rest is a list of enumerable properties and their values that were added to it.

To create it yourself:

```
var error = new Error("ENOENT, no such file or directory 'InvalidFile'");
error.errno = 34;
error.code = 'ENOENT';
error.path = 'InvalidFile';
error.syscall = 'open'

console.log(error);               // uses `util.inspect()`
console.log(util.inspect(error)); // or use it directly

console.log(error.message); // "ENOENT, no such ..."
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(error)); // "[object Error]"
```

And, for a larger sample of the format, try logging some built in modules:

```
console.log(console);
```

```
{ log: [Function],
  info: [Function],
  warn: [Function],
  error: [Function],
  dir: [Function],
  time: [Function],
  timeEnd: [Function],
  trace: [Function],
  assert: [Function],
  Console: [Function: Console] }
```

Comment: I use `throw Error(`, without `new` and it still works. Could you tell me why it works?

Comment: @thefourtheye That's because `Error` [injects the `new` for you](http://es5.github.io/#x15.11.1).

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering subquestion #2.  The accepted answer, though excellent, seems to omit it.

On Node, the [Error: ...] element can be accessed as .stack on the exception object.  It's a string, which you can then parse with regular expressions to get, for instance, the module and line number.

For instance, you could parse the first stack frame like this:

```
...
} catch (e) {
    var msg, file, line, col;
    [msg,file,col] = e.stack.match(/\((.*):(\d+)\)/);
    if (file) {
        [,file,line] = file.match(/(.*):(\d+)/);
    }
}
```